# Setting time for a particular action to be occured -LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

In my LibGdx game,enemies are coming in to the screen one by one.

I want to make enemeies appear at a particular time after the game starts.

How can I do it efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`TimerTest` libGDX demo](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/TimerTest.java) demonstrates your desired behaviour:

```
public class TimerTest extends GdxTest {
    @Override
    public void create () {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Task task = timer.scheduleTask(new Task() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                Gdx.app.log("TimerTest", "ping");
            }
        }, 1, 1);

        Gdx.app.log("TimerTest","is task scheduled: "+String.valueOf(task.isScheduled()));
    }
}
```

This is libGDX's implementation of a Timer/Task.
Create a new `Timer` and a new `Task` via [`Timer.scheduleTask`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html#schedule-com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer.Task-float-). The code in the run method will be executed at every `intervalSeconds` seconds. In this case, it will log a message every second, with a delay of one second.

See the [libGDX documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html) for more.